# Strange new line in my string, how can I remove it?

Tags: php, sql

I'm retrieving data from a database, and some of the values are giving me some issues.
For example sometimes when I print it out on the screen it prints like this:

```
Something here
                Something else here
```

but it should be :

```
Something here Something else here
```

I looked it up and apparently it appears as :

```
Something here _x000B_ Something else here
```

in the database, and I'm not allowed to change it. I'm not even sure what *x000B* is supposed to be but I'm sure that's why I'm having issues.
I tried things like removing spaces like this:

```
$test = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

it remove the spaces but it still appears as this:

```
Somethinghere
                Somethingelsehere
```

Comment: Did you try $test = str_replace('_x000B_', '', $string); ?

Comment: @Haris Yes I tried it.

Comment: Can you show me the exact html code you get? Copy from browser source.

Comment: @Haris It's in the Terminal, and it's exactly like what I wrote in my question already.

Comment: You mention you aren't sure what it's supposed to be. For what it's worth, it's a vertical tab. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character.

Comment: @rrtx2000 Thank you!!! That helped me solve my problem. :)   I used this: str_replace("\v", " ", $string); You would deserve best answer.

Comment: Thanks. That was quick. I'm glad you solved it. I copied our comments into an answer so this question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention you aren't sure what it's supposed to be. For what it's worth, it's a vertical tab. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

Then the reply from Exn:
@rrtx2000 Thank you!!! That helped me solve my problem. :) I used this: str_replace("\v", " ", $string); You would deserve best answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing newline and carriage return characters.

```
str_replace("\n", "", $string);
str_replace("\r", "", $string);
```

Note the use of double quotes.  If you try to use single quotes instead, it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: I have added most of the possibilities.

```
str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t", "\f", "&#x000B;", "_x000B_"), "", $string);
```